# For loop to average over individual time points Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, for-loop, average

I have a 21x2 vector in Matlab that looks like this:

```
A = [0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2.0 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5;
     0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1]';
```

each element in the first row corresponds to either a `0` or `1` in the second row. I need to treat each of the set of `0's` and `1's` as blocks so that I can single out the elements such that I have a vector containing all the **first** elements of the `1` blocks and then another vector containing all the **second** elements of the `1` blocks and so on until I have all the elements separated out.

so for e.g. `vector1=[1.0 2.1]`, `vector2=[1.1 2.2]` etc etc.

This is because I need to average over individual points between blocks so that I have for e.g. avg_vector1, avg_vector2, avg_vector3... etc.

So far I have been trying to write a loop to do this but I can already tell it won't be so efficient and might not work every time because I will have to have a an `if` for each `j` (see below) and the "number of j's" is not really fixed, sometimes the block could be longer, sometimes it could be shorter.

```
j=1;
for i=1:size(A,1)
 if A(i,2)==1
    if j==1 
        vector1(i)=A(i,1);
        j=j+1; %j is acting as a counter for the "size" of the block of 0's and 1's
    if j==2
        vector2(i)=A(i,1);
    **incomplete**
```

Does anyone know how to do this more elegantly and simply?

Thanks

Comment: Will the vector always starts with zeros? Do you know the number of blocks you'll have (always 2)?

Comment: Yes it will start with 0 every time

Comment: In your example, the two blocks of 1's don't have the same size (first has 6 elements and second has 5). Is this a typo, or can it happen in your data vector? Then, you don't have to create several vectors, as `mean` can operate along a given dimension

Comment: No thats not a typo, they are and can be different sizes!

Comment: Then how do you handle the fact that the sizes are different? Do you just take as many values from the longest block as there are in the shortest one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Hopefully) correct version:

```
M = logical(A(:, 2));
is_start = [M(1); ~M(1:end-1) & M(2:end)];
is_start = is_start(M); 
A_valid = A(M, 1);
group_idx = cumsum(is_start); 
group_start_idx = find(is_start);
sub_idx = (1:numel(is_start))' - group_start_idx(group_idx)+1;
means = accumarray(sub_idx, A_valid, [], @mean);
```

There is possibly a slightly neater way of doing this with one or two fewer steps, but this should work.

**Take home lesson:** use `cumsum` more often!

Comment: I think what OP wants is an average over the 2 blocks element by element (i.e. element 1 of first block with element 1 of second and so on). So your `group_idx` would have to be `[0.....0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 ......0 1 2 3 4 5]`. Nice use of cumsum and accumarray though, I should definitely use it more

Comment: Yes @BillBokeey is correct, I want an average element by element over the blocks, so averaging the first elements, then averaging the second elements, averaging the third elements and so on!

Comment: @dan-man thanks this works! Now I'll try to apply to my actual data where the vector is a little bit longer!

Comment: @dan-man you should remove the old answer from this now you have a correct solution.

Comment: I can't think of a more irrelevant information than that. (referring to the comment)

Comment: @dan-man, this works fine for my data. Now I am trying to add in something that will calculate the means for the blocks that are zeros. It would be by changing is_start, `is_start = [M(1); ~M(1:end-1) & M(2:end)];` right? `is_start = [M(1); M(1:end-1) & M(2:end)];` doesn't work

Comment: @MaheenSiddiqui - the "cheat" solution would be to just invert `M`, i.e. `~M`, and copy-paste the rest of the code.  You could update the code for `is_start`, but I'm not going to give you the answer for that...I think you should be able to work it out yourself, with some playing around...that's how you learn!

Comment: @dan-man thanks for the suggestion and yup I'm going to play around with it